# Coinbase API - Keep getting Invalid API Key despite following the documentation

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, coinbase-api

I'm trying to set me up an application to interact with Coinbase API but I'm struggling with the API Key/Secret.

Based on my code:

````js
import { readFile } from 'fs';
import crypto from 'crypto';
import request from 'request';
import { request as rqu } from 'undici';
import fetch, { Headers } from 'node-fetch';
// Import { getJSON } from './sys-handler.mjs';

/**
 * Read Local JSON file
 * No real error management but that should be fine
 *
 * @param {string} file - JSON file to read
 * @returns {object}
 */
function getJSON( file ) {
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        readFile( file, 'utf8', ( err, data ) => {
            if ( err ) {
                reject( err );
            }
            else {
                resolve( JSON.parse( data ) );
            }
        } );
    } );
}

/**
 * Base64 Decode
 * @param {string} str
 * @returns {string}
 */
function atob( str ) {
    return `${ Buffer.from( str, 'base64' ) }`;
}

/**
 * Base64 Encode
 * @param {string} str
 * @returns {string}
 */
function btoa( str ) {
    return `${ Buffer.from( str ).toString( 'base64' ) }`;
}

/**
 * Get API Credentials from base64 Hash
 *
 * Credentials are stored in a string that is composed of the following:
 * - Key
 * - Secret
 * - Passphrase
 *
 * Each is base64 encoded, then they are joined with a colon (:), then the whole string is base64 encoded again.
 *
 * @param {string} file JSON File containing API Credentials
 * @returns {Promise<string[]>}
 */
async function getApiCredentialsFromBase64( file ) {
    try {
        const keys = await getJSON( file );
        return keys.map(
            str => atob( str )
                .split( ':' )
                .map( atob )
        );
    }
    catch ( error ) {
        throw error;
    }
}

/**
 * Get API Credentials from plain text
 *
 * Credentials are stored in clear plain text as they were generated initially in a JSON object as follows:
 * ```javascript
 * {
 *     "key":        "................",
 *     "secret":     "...........................",
 *     "passphrase": "............."
 * }
 * ```
 *
 * @param {string} file JSON File containing API Credentials
 * @returns {Promise<string[]>}
 */
async function getApiCredentialsFromPlainText( file ) {
    try {
        const { key, secret, passphrase } = await getJSON( file );
        return {
            key,
            secret,
            passphrase
        };
    }
    catch ( error ) {
        throw error;
    }
}

/**
 * Ensure path does not start with /
 *
 * @param {string} path
 * @returns {string}
 */
function sanitizePath( path ) {
    return `${ path.replace( /^\/*/gu, '' ) }`;
}

/**
 * Ensure url does not end with /
 *
 * @param {string} url
 * @returns {string}
 */
function sanitizeURL( url ) {
    return `${ url.replace( /\/*$/gu, '' ) }`;
}

/**
 * @typedef {Object} SignatureOptions
 * @property {string} method - HTTP Method
 * @property {string} endpoint - API Endpoint
 * @property {string} body - Request Body
 * @property {number} timestamp - Timestamp
 * @property {string} version - API Version
 * @property {string} credentials - API Credentials File
 */

/**
 * Build Coinbase-formatted Signature
 *
 * A timestamp, the method, the path and the body are all concatenated together to create the `message` string.
 * The `message` string is then signed using the base64 decoded API Secret through an HMAC-sha256.
 *
 * Then, `timestamp`, sanitized `path`, `passphrase`, API Key, the base64 encoded HMAC-sha256 signature and the trailing-slash-free endpoint are returned within an object.
 *
 *
 * @param {SignatureOptions} options - Options
 */
async function buildSignature( {
    timestamp = Math.floor( Date.now() / 1000 ),
    method = 'GET',
    endpoint,
    body,
    credentials,
    version
} ) {
    // Sanitize the path
    const _endpoint = sanitizePath( endpoint );

    let key; let passphrase; let
        secret;

    // Get API Credentials
    if ( credentials.endsWith( '.base64.json' ) ) {
        [ [ key, secret, passphrase ] ] = await getApiCredentialsFromBase64( credentials );
        secret = atob( secret );
    }
    else {
        ( { key, secret, passphrase } = await getApiCredentialsFromPlainText( credentials ) );
    }

    // Build Message
    let message;
    // If a version is provided, it is prepended to the endpoint
    if ( version ) {
        message = `${ timestamp }${ method.toUpperCase() }/${ version }/${ _endpoint }${ body || '' }`;
    }
    else {
        message = `${ timestamp }${ method.toUpperCase() }/${ _endpoint }${ body || '' }`;
    }

    return {
        signature: crypto.createHmac( 'sha256', secret )
            .update( message )
            .digest( 'base64' ),
        timestamp,
        passphrase,
        key,
        endpoint: _endpoint
    };
}


/**
 * @typedef {Object} APIRequestOptions
 * @property {string} api - API URL
 * @property {string} version - API Version
 * @property {string} endpoint - API Endpoint
 * @property {string} credentials - API Key File
 * @property {string|Object} body - Request Body
 * @property {string} method - HTTP Method
 * @property {string} lib - Library used to send request
 * @returns
 */

/**
 * Send API Request
 *
 * @param {APIRequestOptions} options
 * @returns {Promise<*>}
 */
const getAccountInfo = async ( {
    endpoint,
    body,
    method = 'GET',
    version = 'v2',
    sandbox = false,
    credentials = './api.json',
    api,
    lib = 'undici'
} ) => {

    let _api;

    if ( !api ) {
        // Choose the right URL depending on the sandbox mode
        if ( sandbox ) {
            _api = `https://api-public.sandbox.exchange.coinbase.com`;
        }
        else {
            _api = `https://api.exchange.coinbase.com`;
        }
    }
    else {
        _api = `${ sanitizeURL( api ) }`;
    }

    if ( version ) {
        _api = `${ _api }/${ version }`;
    }

    // Build Request Signature
    const {
        key,
        signature,
        passphrase,
        timestamp,
        endpoint: _endpoint
    } = await buildSignature( { method, endpoint, body, credentials, version } );

    // Full Endpoint
    const fullEndpoint = `${ _api }/${ _endpoint }`;

    // Send Request
    return await new Promise( async ( resolve, reject ) => {

        // Craft Request Headers
        const headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'aemi-node-client',
            'CB-ACCESS-KEY': key,
            'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': signature,
            'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
            'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': passphrase,
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        };

        const options = {};

        // Try different libraries to send the request
        switch ( lib ) {
            case 'node-fetch': {
                /*
                 * Craft Request Options
                 * Use object assign as official Coinbase Pro Node Client does
                 * Using the Headers object from node-fetch library
                 */
                Object.assign( options, {
                    headers: new Headers( headers ),
                    method,
                    uri: fullEndpoint,
                    ...body ? { body } : {}
                } );
                // Parse the JSON request or display an error
                try {
                    const response = await fetch( fullEndpoint, options );
                    resolve( await response.json() );
                }
                catch ( error ) {
                    console.error( error );
                    reject( error );
                }

                break;
            }
            case 'request': {
                /*
                 * Craft Request Options
                 * Use object assign as official Coinbase Pro Node Client does
                 */
                Object.assign( options, {
                    headers,
                    method,
                    uri: fullEndpoint,
                    ...body ? { body } : {}
                } );
                // Send Request
                request( options, async ( error, response, data ) => {
                    // Parse the JSON request or display an error
                    try {
                        if ( error ) {
                            reject( error );
                        }
                        else {
                            if ( data ) {
                                resolve( JSON.parse( data ) );
                            }
                            else {
                                resolve( await response.toJSON() );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch ( error ) {
                        reject( error );
                    }
                } );
                break;
            }
            case 'undici':
            default: {
                /*
                 * Craft Request Options
                 * Use object assign as official Coinbase Pro Node Client does
                 */
                Object.assign( options, {
                    headers,
                    method,
                    uri: fullEndpoint,
                    ...body ? { body } : {}
                } );
                // Parse the JSON request or display an error
                try {
                    const response = await rqu( fullEndpoint, options );
                    resolve( await response.body.json() );
                }
                catch ( error ) {
                    console.error( error );
                    reject( error );
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    } );
};

// API URLs tested
const apis = [
    'https://api.pro.coinbase.com',
    'https://api.exchange.coinbase.com',
    'https://api-public.sandbox.exchange.coinbase.com',
    'https://api-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com'
];

// API Key files
const apiKeys = [
    './api.base64.json', // View Rights on Coinbase Pro (1st key generated)
    './api.test.base64.json', // View Rights on Coinbase Pro (2nd Key generated)
    './api.sandbox.base64.json', // View Rights on Coinbase Pro Sandbox Mode
    './api.plain.json' // View Rights on Coinbase Pro (same as api.test.base64)
];

// Libraries tested to send request
const libs = [
    'undici',
    'request',
    'node-fetch'
];

// Test Endpoint that requires authentication
const endpoint = '/accounts';

// Avoid ESLint parsing problem about await outside an async function
( async () => {
    for ( const lib of libs ) {
        for ( const version of [ '', 'v2' ] ) {
            for ( const key of apiKeys ) {
                for ( const api of apis ) {
                    const options = { api, version, endpoint, credentials: key, lib };
                    console.log( `// ---- ----- ---- //` );
                    try {
                        const response = await getAccountInfo( options );
                        options.return = JSON.stringify( response, 0, 0 );
                    }
                    catch ( error ) {
                        console.error( `//      Error      //` );
                        let errorString;
                        try {
                            errorString = JSON.stringify( error, 0, 0 );
                        }
                        catch ( _ ) {
                            errorString = error;
                        }
                        options.return = errorString;
                    }
                    console.log( options );
                    console.log( `// ---- ----- ---- //` );
                }
            }
        }
    }
} )();
````

...I keep getting (logs have been truncated because of Stack Overflow characters limit and I removed the combinations `(exchange|pro)-key/(exchange|pro)-sandbox-mode`):

```js
// ---- ----- ---- //
{
  api: 'https://api.pro.coinbase.com',
  version: '',
  endpoint: '/accounts',
  credentials: './api.base64.json',
  lib: 'undici',
  return: '{"message":"invalid signature"}'
}
// ---- ----- ---- //
// ---- ----- ---- //
{
  api: 'https://api.exchange.coinbase.com',
  version: '',
  endpoint: '/accounts',
  credentials: './api.base64.json',
  lib: 'undici',
  return: '{"message":"invalid signature"}'
}
// ---- ----- ---- //
// ---- ----- ---- //
{
  api: 'https://api.pro.coinbase.com',
  version: '',
  endpoint: '/accounts',
  credentials: './api.test.base64.json',
  lib: 'undici',
  return: '{"message":"invalid signature"}'
}
// ---- ----- ---- //
// ---- ----- ---- //
{
  api: 'https://api.exchange.coinbase.com',
  version: '',
  endpoint: '/accounts',
  credentials: './api.test.base64.json',
  lib: 'undici',
  return: '{"message":"invalid signature"}'
}
// ---- ----- ---- //
// ---- ----- ---- //
{
  api: 'https://api-public.sandbox.exchange.coinbase.com',
  version: '',
  endpoint: '/accounts',
  credentials: './api.sandbox.base64.json',
  lib: 'undici',
  return: '{"message":"invalid signature"}'
}
// ---- ----- ---- //
// ---- ----- ---- //
{
  api: 'https://api-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com',
  version: '',
  endpoint: '/accounts',
  credentials: './api.sandbox.base64.json',
  lib: 'undici',
  return: '{"message":"invalid signature"}'
}
// ---- ----- ---- //
// ---- ----- ---- //
{
  api: 'https://api.pro.coinbase.com',
  version: '',
  endpoint: '/accounts',
  credentials: './api.plain.json',
  lib: 'undici',
  return: '{"message":"invalid signature"}'
}
// ---- ----- ---- //
// ---- ----- ---- //
{
  api: 'https://api.exchange.coinbase.com',
  version: '',
  endpoint: '/accounts',
  credentials: './api.plain.json',
  lib: 'undici',
  return: '{"message":"invalid signature"}'
}
// ---- ----- ---- //
// ---- ----- ---- //
{
  api: 'https://api.pro.coinbase.com',
  version: 'v2',
  endpoint: '/accounts',
  credentials: './api.base64.json',
  lib: 'undici',
  return: '{"message":"invalid signature"}'
}
// ---- ----- ---- //
// ---- ----- ---- //
{
  api: 'https://api.exchange.coinbase.com',
  version: 'v2',
  endpoint: '/accounts',
  credentials: './api.base64.json',
  lib: 'undici',
  return: '{"message":"invalid signature"}'
}
// ---- ----- ---- //
// ---- ----- ---- //
{
  api: 'https://api.pro.coinbase.com',
  version: 'v2',
  endpoint: '/accounts',
  credentials: './api.test.base64.json',
  lib: 'undici',
  return: '{"message":"invalid signature"}'
}
// ---- ----- ---- //
// ---- ----- ---- //
{
  api: 'https://api.exchange.coinbase.com',
  version: 'v2',
  endpoint: '/accounts',
  credentials: './api.test.base64.json',
  lib: 'undici',
  return: '{"message":"invalid signature"}'
}
// ---- ----- ---- //
// ---- ----- ---- //
{
  api: 'https://api-public.sandbox.exchange.coinbase.com',
  version: 'v2',
  endpoint: '/accounts',
  credentials: './api.sandbox.base64.json',
  lib: 'undici',
  return: '{"message":"invalid signature"}'
}
// ---- ----- ---- //
// ---- ----- ---- //
{
  api: 'https://api-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com',
  version: 'v2',
  endpoint: '/accounts',
  credentials: './api.sandbox.base64.json',
  lib: 'undici',
  return: '{"message":"invalid signature"}'
}
// ---- ----- ---- //
// ---- ----- ---- //
{
  api: 'https://api.pro.coinbase.com',
  version: 'v2',
  endpoint: '/accounts',
  credentials: './api.plain.json',
  lib: 'undici',
  return: '{"message":"invalid signature"}'
}
// ---- ----- ---- //
// ---- ----- ---- //
{
  api: 'https://api.exchange.coinbase.com',
  version: 'v2',
  endpoint: '/accounts',
  credentials: './api.plain.json',
  lib: 'undici',
  return: '{"message":"invalid signature"}'
}
// ---- ----- ---- //
// ... It goes the same way with other used libraries.
```

If I'm dumb as f*ck, tell me but please tell me what's wrong with this code too. I'm not sure the API URLs are correct but every URLs Coinbase provides resulted in unsuccessful trials.

*Edit: Code has been commented and detailed precisely, and logs provided have not been manipulated unless specified.*

Thank you all,

Best Regards

Comment: Is it possible that your API key is invalid?

Comment: Probabilities that `key`, `secret` and `passphrase` are wrong are quite inexistant unless you tell me that the API page for Coinbase Exchange shown me wrong API key, wrong secret and the passphrase I set has not been correctly remembered but it's very unlikely. Did you spot anything in the code that is incorrect ?

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest you probably have an invalid key. I've seen CB invalidate my Key out of nowhere and I have to get a new one.

If you were having problems with your signature you'd get more appropriate errors.

Something like:

- invalid signature
- timestamp has expired
- etc.

Comment: Hi @ thanks for your comment. I updated my code to precisely display every errors I get with every combinations I try. The `api.test.json` is a key I generated after your comment to verify if it was the key. The `api.json` is the first one I generated for the classic Coinbase Exchange... and the `api.explicit.json` is obviously the one for the Sandbox mode.
Also, I discovered there was a `https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/` API URL that I didn't know it existed before. I don't see what I can do better for now.

Comment: @GuillaumeC. where are you generating the key? i don't think a key generated on coinbase.com will work on pro.coinbase.com and likewise the other way around. One works for wallets and the other works for profiles. make sure the coinbase.com keys are using the coinbase api and the pro keys are using the pro or exchange api endpoints. `invalid signature` tells me the key is good but the signature wasn't encrypted correctly.

Comment: @GuillaumeC. for what it's worth the coinbase pro node api found here still works 100% you can reverse engineer it or use it out of the box.  https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-pro-node

Comment: I looked at Coinbase Pro node api and honestly I'm doing quite the same job but with more comment and (IMHO) in a more understandable way. Keep failing with my code I just updated to be the most complete and commented as possible. I discovered that `https://api.pro.coinbase.com` existed and therefore its sandbox mode counterpart but I don't understand what keys should be used for one or another apart from the fact that I only use keys generated in Coinbase Pro environment and not in Coinbase standard environment. I'll give a try to the official client now.

Comment: Thanks @genericHCU for your help, if you have any clue, please tell me. I'm going to contact Coinbase directly for now.

Comment: to my knowledge the keys generated in pro should work in api.pro.coinbase.com, api.exchange.coinbase.com and the sandbox. the fact that all of your returns are providing invalid signature are telling me the keys are good and you're not encrypting the message correctly.

Comment: I gave a try to the Official Client and despite the quite exactly (apparently) _same_ code, the official client works and mine does not. I'm currently waiting for an answer from Coinbase.